# Blink LED for first 5 seconds, stay solid for last 5 seconds on button press (Arduino)

Tags: timer, arduino, led

So this is probably not that hard, but I'm a bit stumped. I have a button that is the "Take picture" button in a larger control panel. Right now the LED flips on for 10 seconds then flips off. I'd like it to blink for the first 5 seconds, then stay solid for the last 5 seconds. Not sure how to go about that, I've tried some guessing, but no go. Here's what I have so far, its currently long and ugly:

```
// take a picture button


const int shoot_pin = 5;
const int shoot_led = 13; 

int shoot_state = 0;
int last_shoot_state = 0;


long shoot_timer;
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay = 10;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers


void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(shoot_pin, INPUT);
   pinMode(shoot_led, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  int shoot_reading = digitalRead(shoot_pin);

  if (shoot_reading != last_shoot_state) { lastDebounceTime = millis(); } 

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {

    if (shoot_reading != shoot_state) {
      shoot_state = shoot_reading;

      if (shoot_state == HIGH) {
          digitalWrite(shoot_led, HIGH);
          shoot_timer = millis();
          Serial.println("Counting down...5 seconds"); // for tracking
          delay(5000);
          Serial.println("Shooting Picture"); // for tracking - eventually will be a keypress

      } // end of high

    } // end of reading

  }// end of that giant nested debaounce

  last_shoot_state = shoot_reading;

  // right now just stays lit for 10 seconds
  if (millis() - shoot_timer >= 10000){ digitalWrite(shoot_led, LOW);}

} // end of loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your delay with a call to a custom function that blinks for you (blinkLED, in this case) and then reduce the on time from 10 secs to 5

```
// take a picture button


const int shoot_pin = 5;
const int shoot_led = 13; 

int shoot_state = 0;
int last_shoot_state = 0;


long shoot_timer;
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay = 10;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers


void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(shoot_pin, INPUT);
   pinMode(shoot_led, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  int shoot_reading = digitalRead(shoot_pin);

  if (shoot_reading != last_shoot_state) { lastDebounceTime = millis(); } 

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {

    if (shoot_reading != shoot_state) {
      shoot_state = shoot_reading;

      if (shoot_state == HIGH) {
          digitalWrite(shoot_led, HIGH);
          shoot_timer = millis();
          Serial.println("Counting down...5 seconds"); // for tracking
          delay(5000);
          blinkLED(13, 500, 500, 5);
          Serial.println("Shooting Picture"); // for tracking - eventually will be a keypress

      } // end of high

    } // end of reading

  }// end of that giant nested debounce

  last_shoot_state = shoot_reading;

  // turn on LED for 5 seconds
  digitalWrite(shoot_led, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(shoot_led, HIGH);

} // end of loop

void blinkLED(int pinNumber, int onLength, int offLength, int repetitions){
    for(int i=0; i < repetitions; i++){    
        digitalWrite(pinNumber, LOW); //on
        delay(onLength);
        digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH); //off
        delay(offLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is giving me a "variable or field 'blinkLED' declared void error.

Comment: I am not in front of my compiler, let me take a look at it.

Comment: I think I found the problem with my custom fucntion and updated the code, I was not declaring each of the variables it used to be an int, that what happens when you program in a bunch of languages! :D

Comment: Ok that worked out great. :) I had to shuffle the last delay to the button and declare the pin LOW at the start of the loop to work with the debounce. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help, if the answer is correct for you, please mark it so. And pay the SO help forward when you can help someone :D

Comment: It looks like you tried to edit my post to be your answer. Some things in your edit were not really correct programming for Arduino, like not listing the custom function last. The reviewers decided it chanegd too much of the answer and wasn't ok...you can't just move functions around like in some languages...

Comment: Ok. Well, I would like to show at least the delay move and the low pin setting. If that is ok?